# CSS transition event not fired in jQuery when there is no property change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I've run into an interesting case that isn't explicitly covered in the [W3C CSS Transitions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transitions/#transition-events-) spec or the [MDN CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions) doc that I thought I would share because it cost me a bit of time.

If you "change" a CSS transitioned property to the same value then no transitioned event is fired. As I think about I can see why this would be the default behavior, but it can easily cause issues for the unsuspecting developer with something like this:
`$("#test").css("opacity", "1").bind("transitionend", doneFn);`

In the above code, if the element in question happens to have a opacity of 1 then the doneFn will never be called. Also see http://jsfiddle.net/studgeek/Xj8TB/.

To make this is a question, is there a good workaround for handling this?

You could compare the property value to the existing property value to the existing property value but that is trickier than it sounds to do it well because css property values can take so many forms - different units, and even string values like auto. So you really have to test the objects actual state, which of course needs to be done different for each property. Ugh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One work-around would be to make your own jQuery method for setting a CSS value that would handle everything for you.  It would get the current value of the property, set the new value, check to see if the value had changed.  If it had not, then it would fire the completion function manually:

```
// globally set this to the right transition event for the current browser
// modernizr has ways of using feature detection to know which is the right way to set this
var transitionEvent = "webkitTransitionEnd";

jQuery.fn.transitionTo = function(prop, value, completeFn) {
    var origValue, item;
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        item = jQuery(this[i]);
        origValue = item.css(prop);
        item.css(prop, value);

        // if value hasn't changed           
        if (origValue == item.css(prop)) {
            completeFn.apply(this[i]);
        } else {
            this.one(transitionEvent, completeFn);
        }
    }
}
```

In your example above, it would work like this:

```
$("#test").transitionTo("opacity", "1", doneFn);
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LHdGR/

This plug-in could be expanded to support passing a map of multiple properties like the `.css()` supports too.

The only other option I can think of is to read the transtionDuration and set a timeout value for slightly longer than that.  If the transitionEnd event fires, you cancel the timeout.  If it doesn't fire, the timeout can manually fire the transitionEnd event.  The code for this could work like this:

```
var transitionEvent = "webkitTransitionEnd";
var transitionDuration = "WebkitTransitionDuration";

// get transition duration in decimal seconds
// this only returns the first transition time if there are multiple ones specified
jQuery.fn.getDuration = function() {
    var val = this.css(transitionDuration);
    if (!val) {
        val = "0s";
    }
    var num = parseFloat(val);
    var units = val.replace(/\d\., /g, "");
    if (units.indexOf("ms") == 0) {
        num /= 1000;
    }
    return(num);
}

// set a guaranteed transition event that will always fire, even if
// no CSS transition is triggered
jQuery.fn.setTransitionEvent = function(completeFn) {
    var item, duration;
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        item = jQuery(this[i]);
        duration = Math.ceil((Number(item.getDuration()) + 0.1) * 1000);
        (function(t, o) {
            var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                completeFn.apply(o);
                o.unbind(transitionEvent);
            }, duration);
            o.one(transitionEvent, function() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            });
        })(duration, item);
    }
}
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hxevW/

Comment: Yes, that was what I suggested at the end of my question, and have some code that does this for all the properties and also checks to see if they are even transitioned properties. Unfortunately taht doesn't even cover it because of units. What if you are setting `100px` but the element is at `1em` which happens to equal `100px`? Or an even simpler case, you are setting `left` to `0` but `css(left)` returns `0px`. It feels the current approach of not firing if no change has created a bit of mess.

Comment: @studgeek - my code handles the 0 and 0px issue because I compare the results of .css(prop) before and after so it should return consistent values regardless.  I don't compare to what is passed in for that exact reason.

Comment: @studgeek - the only other thing I can think of is using a timeout.  I added that to the end of my answer.

Comment: That's a nice touch of testing the after value @jfriend00. Will it return that value immediately even though its in transition?

Comment: And I guess we have to test the transition-property to make sure the property in question is transitioned and the transition-duration to make sure its greater than 0. Ugh again.

Comment: @studgeek - you can't have your cake and eat it too here.  Either you want to force doneFn to be called or not.  You're making it awfully hard on yourself if you only want it to be called when everything is specified in the CSS for a transition, but no transition will actually fire because you aren't actually changing any relevant CSS.  Yuck!  It's way easier to fix your code so that doneFn can just always be fired and use one of these work-arounds to always fire it.

Comment: Actually, the CSS is being changed, its just that the CSS change may not result in an element state change. This applies for changing classes also which means there are cases you really can detect. So I think I am back to my original thought, that the current spec approach of not firing transitioned if there is not a state change means you can't really depend on the transitioned event - which will burn a lot of developers. Probably the most practical approach is do a timeout like you suggest, but that can be wrong also (transition isn't guaranteed to start right away).

Comment: thanks for your thoughts and sample code. I'm going to +1, but hope for a better answer - though I don't see what it could be.

Comment: What I was saying was that if there's no state change, then the CSS isn't really being changed.   If you don't want any of these work-arounds, then it's time for you to go redesign why you're requiring a transition end event when there is no actual transition that runs.  That may be easier to fix.

Comment: I absolutely understand what you are saying @jfriend00 (and hope I am not sounding like I am disagreeing with your points), but for libraries you may not be able to redesign and its clearly a lot of work to handle all the permutations. The CSS can actually change in many ways that may not result in a graphical change so no transition event will be fired. So I still think its gotcha in the current spec that will burn many folks, that said I'm not 100% sure that sending a transition event when no real graphical change happened is a better approach either. Oh well.

Comment: @studgeek - Well, the browser-behavior is what it is.  If you want to argue that the built-in behavior should be changed, you will need to go talk to the standards committee and see if you can convince them that all browsers should change their implementation.  That's not something any of us here can do much about.  I thought we were talking here about ways to work around the current behavior.

Comment: As I look my question again I agree you are right, I was asking for a workaround. And yours is the best so far, and certainly in the right direction. So I'll mark it answered. Thanks for your time on this.